# Sending an image file to a broadcast receiver

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

I want to pass image file to another broadcast receiver using `intent`, since the Android documentation suggest to pass data values not files.

How can I achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to pass image file to Android broadcast receiver you have to convert the file to bytes array and send using `putExtra` method

```
intent.putExtra("myImage", convertBitmapToByteArray(bitmapImage));

byte[] convertBitmapToByteArray(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = null;
    try {
        baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
        return baos.toByteArray();
    } finally {
        if (baos != null) {
            try {
                baos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(BitmapUtils.class.getSimpleName(), "ByteArrayOutputStream was not closed");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can convert back to image in your broadcast receiver

```
byte[] byteArray = intent.getByteArrayExtra("myImage");

Bitmap myImage = convertCompressedByteArrayToBitmap(byteArray);

Bitmap convertCompressedByteArrayToBitmap(byte[] src) {
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(src, 0, src.length);
}
```